# Python: apply a list of lambda functions to a list without loops

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, filter

I have a list of lambda functions and a list of scores which I want to apply the functions to.

I want to return a new list consisting of max score after applying those lambda functions.

For example:

```
calculate_best_scores([lambda x : x + 1, lambda x : x * 2,\
lambda x : x - 1], [3, 4, 5]) will return [6, 8, 10] --- the max individual max score after applying the lambda function to.
```

Can someone give me advice on how to do this only with lambda functions and map, filter and reduce without explicitly using loops?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to say "lambda function". A function is a function, whether defined by a lambda expression or a `def` statement.

Comment: "Give me advice" is hard to answer without simply handing you a full solution -- which we try not to do here.  How far did you get after working through tutorials on the topic?  You need to `map` each function in your first list to each value in your second list, and then choose the max value for each value -- which I'm guessing you already know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
>>> functions = [lambda x : x + 1, lambda x : x * 2, lambda x : x - 1]
>>> data = [3, 4, 5]
>>> result = [max([f(x) for f in functions]) for x in data]
>>> result
[6, 8, 10]
```